# How to resolve the error this bundle is invalid when i validated the app

Tags: iphone

I got the error when I validate the app

This bundle is invalid. The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at least the CFBundleTypeName key

Comment: did you mess with the plist file manually ?

Comment: Please show us your Plist as it appears in XCode, feel free to censor any information you may think of as sensitive.

Comment: well I don't know about this. Actually, first time i resubmission the app on app store, I follow all the steps but finally when I validate the app then gets this above metion error

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I deleted the "Document Types" key in my Info.plist.  I had nothing in the entry, not sure where it came from.

Answer (score 8):

In the Info.Plist CFBundleDocumentTypes key you will have an line with `<dict/>` on it.  Delete this `<dict/>` line and the error will go away.

So the following:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict/>
    </array>
```

Becomes:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
    </array>
```

Then everything works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem, and the problem was in the info.plist file, I had in the document types tab an empty tag (added by mistake) when I removed this tag all went OK for me.